# What are TypeErrors? One of them appeared in my code

Tags: python, typeerror

Why is this error coming? It is a TypeError. And also, what are TypeErrors anyways?

All the code needed:

```
from collections import namedtuple
account = namedtuple('person', 'password')

acc1 = account('example', 'passwordex1')
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\Secret.py", line 4, in <module>
    acc1 = account('example', 'passwordex1')
TypeError: __new__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=typeerror#TypeError

Comment: Please read the documentation for how you're supposed to use a `namedtuple`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 1):

`namedtuple('person', 'password')` creates a type `person` with one field (`password`). You want this instead:

```
account = namedtuple('account', ('person', 'password'))
```

Comment: You can also use the syntax, account = namedtuple('account', 'person password')